# How does prolonged (multiday) fasting work?

Tags: fast-days, megillat-esther, yonah-jonah-book-of

In [Esther 4](http://biblehub.com/jps/esther/4.htm):16, Esther tells Mordecai to have the entire Jewish community fast for three straight days:

> ‘Go, gather together all the Jews that are present in Shushan, and fast ye for me, and neither eat nor drink three days, night or day; I also and my maidens will fast in like manner; and so will I go in unto the king, which is not according to the law; and if I perish, I perish.’

And in [Jonah 3](http://biblehub.com/jps/jonah/3.htm), there also seems to be a suggestion of some sort of prolonged fasting (though it's less explicit):

> Now Nineveh was an exceeding great city, of three days’ journey. And Jonah began to enter into the city a day’s journey, and he proclaimed, and said: ‘Yet forty days, and Nineveh shall be overthrown.’ And the people of Nineveh believed G-d; and they proclaimed a fast, and […] And [the king] caused it to be proclaimed and published through Nineveh by the decree of the king and his nobles, saying: ‘Let neither man nor beast, herd nor flock, taste any thing; let them not feed, nor drink water; […] Who knoweth whether G-d will not turn and repent, and turn away from His fierce anger, that we perish not?’

How do such extended fasts work?

I've met many people who aren't able to completely fast for even 25 hours or so for Yom Kippur. Is it just a matter of motivation — that the people of Shushan and of Nineveh were more afraid during these events than we are on Yom Kippur? Or did Hashem lend them strength to continue fasting? Or something else?

Comment: Common advice is that you can survive 3 days without water, eg. http://www.livescience.com/32320-how-long-can-a-person-survive-without-water.html

Comment: @DoubleAA: Thanks. I wasn't really asking about how the people are still *not dead* at the end of the fast, but since you raise the point -- if a typical healthy person can only survive three days without water, then how did the elderly, infirm, pregnant, nursing, etc., survive fasting that long?

Comment: Sick and weak people are exempt from fasting, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA: On the modern liturgical fast days, yes. But on a three-day fast, almost *everyone* would be "sick and weak" after one or two days, so presumably that's not what Esther had in mind. ;-)

Comment: I don't know why you say that... :-)

Comment: I wonder if it was a fast each day and able to recover (eat and drink al little at night) or a full 72 hours.

Comment: @sabbahillel: FWIW, for the Esther case, she specifies "שְׁלֹשֶׁת יָמִים לַיְלָה וָיוֹם" *shloshet yamim layla vayom*, meaning "three days, night and day". I take that to mean a full 72 hours, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ruakh Thank you, I would take it the same way.

Comment: i know people who have taken on 3 day fasts. it's hard but doable for a normal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see (in my Lublin-style *Mikraos G'dolos*) any commentary note how many days the Nineveh folks fasted. I'd have to assume, absent other knowledge, that they fasted until the end of the day the fast was proclaimed, or maybe only the entire next day. (That's what I'd do if an announcement were made in the king's name that everyone must fast, with no duration specified.)

The Esther fast is of course harder to explain that way: it says it was to last "three days, night and day". But it was only three days: the *Bavli*, *Y'vamos* 121 *amud* 2, says that there was no miracle in their surviving this 72-hour fast.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Maharal in Ohr Chadash](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14191&st=&pgnum=155) (on Megillas Esther) it means that you fast at the end of the first day, the whole 24 hours of the second day and a part of the third.

Comment: How does that fit with שְׁלֹשֶׁת יָמִים לַיְלָה וָיוֹם?

Comment: @DoubleAA As the Maharal explains there, *miktzas hayom k'kulo* (and otherwise it should have said שלשה ימים ושלשה לילות).

Comment: @Loewian How I wish we could apply that to other fasts...

Comment: @DoubleAA ;) (Though, correct me if I'm wrong - I don't think we ever say it by something that is only one day - only by the last day of a series...)

Comment: @Loewian Aveilut for a Shemu'a Rechoka (Pesachim 4a).

Comment: @Loewian your parenthetic remark in your 1st comment touches on an interesting nuance in the phrasing, which is probably exactly why Maharal explained it that way. It may have little to do with the "miktzat hayom" rule, or, perhaps, that rule emanates from this phrasing? (The gemarah, after all, came much later than Megilat Esther!)

Comment: @Dan The Maharal says both. He applies the logic of Miktzas Hayom and points to the wording.