# How the 72 hours straight fast was possibly allowed?

Tags: purim, fast-days, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

We know that the danger of fasting two consecutive days is the reason Yom Kippur (and all other fasts) is not celebrated two days outside Israel.

And still Ester commanded on the 3-day fast ([Ester 4,16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.4.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> לֵךְ כְּנוֹס אֶת־כָּל־הַיְּהוּדִים הַנִּמְצְאִים בְּשׁוּשָׁן
>   **וְצוּמוּ עָלַי וְאַל־תֹּאכְלוּ וְאַל־תִּשְׁתּוּ שְׁלֹשֶׁת יָמִים לַיְלָה וָיוֹם**
>
> "Go, assemble all the Jews who live in Shushan, and fast in my behalf; do not eat or drink for three days, night or day."

(thanks to Dr. Shmuel) Although some Poskim do not accept it literally claiming it could not be possible, most do, according to "מיהו בגמ' יבמות קכ"א ע"ב משמע שהיו רצופים וכן פירש"י במגילה דף ט"ו ע"א יעו"ש".

How Halachicly possible was instituting the 3-day fast for the whole people incl. kids and elders?

Comment: Although I have no textual source currently to support this, only practical experience, I’ll offer something to consider. There are different types of fasting. Many emphasize the relationship between burning body fat with the burning of the fat of the Korban on the altar. This is a fast involving food. The type of fast which is life threatening beyond 48-72 hours includes elimination of water. But if water is permitted, the danger to life is eliminated in almost all cases. If water only is allowed one can fast literally for months. This is because the body switches to ketosis (fat-burning).

Comment: In a state of extended ketosis, there is also a distinct change in perception, a clarity of mind and an increase in energy. This altered perception is what opens up the new spiritual service. A fast which also excludes water is like the 25 hour fast of Yom Kippur. Purim sameach!

Comment: Perhaps she enjoined upon the Jews a Monday-Thursday-Monday set of fasts, like those done in a time of drought in Eretz Yisrael? That would be eminently traditional (as a 72 hour fast is not) and there would be no danger to life.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65467/170

Comment: By eating at night when each if the three fasts ended?

Comment: @Dude לילה ויום the fast was at night too

Comment: Is *the danger of fasting two consecutive days* more dangerous than the complete extermination of all Jews from within the realms of the Babylonian empire, which is what Esther was trying to prevent from happening ?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, because we hold that בריא ושמא בריא עדיף - the danger of extermination in 11 months was PROBABLE while fasting for 3 days is a sure danger! Halachicly we can't accept that.

Comment: @AlBerko: It was more than probable, since imperial commands and royal decrees have been issued to that extent (3:9-15, 4:8). Furthermore, the Biblical expression *n days and n nights* is a well-known Hebrew [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom), explained in the Talmud as also including partial days-and-nights. Since the text does not stipulate when exactly within its first day the fast began, nor when exactly within its last day it ended, it could have been as short as only 48 hours or thereabouts, say, from the (after)noon of its first day to the (after)noon of its third or final day.

Answer (score 1):

Kaf HaChaim (תרפו:ל) mentions medrash which says that they would stop for a day.

> ל) שם. זכר לתענית אסתר.  ואעפ"י שאותן היו בניסן לא רצו להתענות בניסן לפי שבו נגאלו אבותינו ממצרים והוקם בו המשכן. טור. לבוש. במדרש **וצומו עלי ג' ימים וכי אפשר לאדם לעשות כן אלא שהיו מפסיקין מבעוד יום**. ופי' הריב"ש סי' תי"ו שלא היו ג' צומות רצופים אלא בלתי רצופים כגון בה"ב אלא שבכל אחד יפסיק מבע"י כמו ביוה"כ ולזה אמר לילה ויום. א"ר או' ח' מיהו בגמ' יבמות קכ"א ע"ב משמע שהיו רצופים וכן פירש"י במגילה דף ט"ו ע"א יעו"ש:

Comment: מיהו בגמ' יבמות קכ"א ע"ב משמע שהיו רצופים וכן פירש"י במגילה דף ט"ו ע"א יעו"ש You might want to start mentioning that that's a Machlokes and some interpret it differently from the Pshat.

Comment: אזי מה שאלתך ותנתן לך

Comment: Isn't it begging the question - because it's impossible - it's impossible and should be interpreted differently?

Comment: Sorry- I actually didn’t read the end of that.

Comment: I included your answer in the question

Comment: Is that what he’s saying? I’m reading it as they would break their fast while it was still day.

Comment: I too read it like @LN6595